# Can I please get a concrete example of the "bond class" (from the anti-if-campain website)?

Tags: java, design-patterns

There is a [website](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/index.html) (called the Anti-if campaign) that talks about how to replace big nested if-statements with something more maintainable (through the use of a 'bond class' see [example](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/articles/the-simplest-anti-if-code.html)). I understand the concept, but I don't know how to implement it (even with the [example](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/articles/the-simplest-anti-if-code.html)).

**Question:**
May I get a concrete example of how to implement this (ie, the bond class)? - it has been bugging me for some time now. Java is my preference, but any examples are welcome.

**note**
I have found one more article on this in stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167589/anti-if-campaign)

Comment: To me looks like a weird Visitor pattern.

Comment: I'd say thats a nice example of the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Comment: ... they have nice front page but only one (1) single article with questionable content ;-) To me this looks more like a result from a web design course than like real campaign to move something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This special technique to avoid if-else-if constructs like shown in the example on that campaigns website can be found in in [Clean Code by Robert C. Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). If you follow his basic advices, you don't need to join the campaign ;)

The example at the referenced page looks dramatic mainly because the code is poorly formatted. This is how it should look like:

```
// Bond class
double calculateValue() {
  if(_type == BTP)  { 
    return calculateBTPValue();
  } else if(_type == BOT) { 
    return calculateBOTValue();    
  } else {
    return calculateEUBValue();
  }
}
```

The recommendation is to replace the condition with polymorphism, which isn't even the best ideas. A better design is to use composition:

```
public interface BondType {
  public double calculate();
}

public class BOT implements BondType { 
  //...
}

public class Bond {
  private BondType type;
  public Bond(BondType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  public doublce calculateValue() {
    return type.calculate();
  }
}
```

Here we got rid of the conditions and delegated the calculation to a new type class.

Answer (score 6):

Unless I'm missing something, I'm not sure how that idea even merits a website of it's own.

It just reads like Polymorphism, which is a fundamental part of good, nay *any*, OO design.

To steal a link from the other question you posted:

[Replace Condition With Polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)

Bond is just the example they have used to demonstrate with.  It represents a financial Bond rather than some OO concept or pattern.

Comment: Hmmmm, I think I miss-read the anti-if web site in that case. It makes more sense to me now (bond class... *embarresed*). For some reason I thought that his example was suggesting something like what C# now has with its somewhat scary [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)... cheers