# does elegant design means removing all 'if-else'? or we need balance

Tags: design-patterns

I don't want to be that extreme by saying "all"

I was having the impression that beautiful design removes a lot of if else
polymorphism  replaces switch-case. Today I read another topic, which uses inheritance to remove if-else.

In my understanding, design typically means make people feel familiar about the concept in the program, so that people can easily change/extend the program. But sometimes I felt that people are also convenient with 'if-else'.

is there some guidelines so that at times we should prefer the OO concept while other scenarios we should use just 'if-else'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we need to distinguish between refactoring complex if-else statements and if-else logic used for class hierarchies.

We will **always** need if-else blocks, and your code can still be elegant with them. But like all code, it must be maintained and readable.

if-esle blocks are not elegant when used for checking class hierarchies. For example:

```
if(object.instanceof derivedClassA) {
    object.doMethod();
}
else if(object.instanceof derivedClassB) {
    ....
}
else if(object.instanceof baseClass) {
}
...
```

This could ***and*** should be handled using OOP techniques, such as inheritance and polymorphism. But, as with any techniques intended to improve code, OOP can be abused and over-used. I always try to avoid over-using inheritance by using a [Strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_design_pattern), which promotes preferring `HAS-A` relations over `IS-A`.

Answer (score 0):

One convention which might apply in this case is the good old 'Rule of Three':

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)

Comment: seems I am steering the topic to re-factoring which is not what I intended originally.

Answer (score 0):

There is some vehement and kitsch opinion on this see: http://www.antiifcampaign.com/.

It is important to note that there are many languages without polymorphism and there are many scenarios where runtime polymorphism cannot be justified on performance grounds even if the language supports it. For example, a N-body problem would be a place to use polymorphism, even though it would work.

I like this subject on SO [anti-if campaign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167589/anti-if-campaign)

Answer (score 0):

if ... else ...

is the most readable when looking at sequential code. Problems arise when we nest or chain them as the reader often can't follow the logic.

if friday
  go home early
else if wednesday
  drink coffee
else if saturday or sunday
  stay home

Nested if statements are even more confusing.

In these cases a switch-type statement is clearer as it looks like a table - again a style the reader finds palatable for multiple choice

switch day
  case wednesday: drink coffee
  case friday: go home early
  case saturday, sunday: stay home

When we know the option in advance, then there are better ways to approach it.

def test(v):
  if v == 'a':
    do something
  elif v == 'b':
    do something else

test('a')
test('b')

is inefficient and unclear. You are better off with separately named methods or, if v comes from an external source, a dictionary.

choices =
  a: do something
  b: do something else

choices['a']?()
choices['b']?()

This last example is less sudo-code and more coffeescript. The ? before the function call means that the call is not made if the dictionary reference was not valid.

I have just read Andy's response. Rules of three is everywhere - and for good reason. As I discussed above, too much information causes confusion. I talk about rules of three in my blog - especially when talking about design by decomposition.