# How replace If-else block condition

Tags: if-statement, design-patterns, anti-patterns

In my code I have an if-else block condition like this:

```
public String method (Info info) {
    if (info.isSomeBooleanCondition) {
        return "someString";
    }
    else if (info.isSomeOtherCondition) {
        return "someOtherString";
    }
    else if (info.anotherCondition) {
        return "anotherStringAgain";
    }
    else if (lastCondition) {
        return "string ...";
    }
    else return "lastButNotLeastString";
}
```

Each conditional branch returns a String.

Since if-else statements are difficult to read, test and maintain, how can I replace?
I was thinking to use Chain Of Responsability Pattern, is it right in this case?
Is there any other elegant way that I can do that?

Comment: I find it hard to follow the logic of the [blog post](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/eliminate-branching-if-statements-to-produce-better-code) you mention in the comment to @melponeme 's answer. It goes from "overuse of deeply nested if/else is bad" directly to "we should never use if/else" without really explaining that conclusion. Could you expand on how the code you posted is a hindrance to readability and maintenance?

Comment: If-else is not an anti pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1167628/1168342 Your example is not difficult to read or maintain. Nested ifs or the arrow anti pattern is another beast. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am left to assume that your code does not exist in the `Info` class as it is passed in an referenced for all but that last condition. My first instinct would be to make `String OtherClass.method(Info)` into `String Info.method()` and have it return the appropriate string.

Next, I would take a look at the conditions. Are they really conditions or can they be mapped to a table. Whenever I see code performing a lookup, such as this, I tend to fall back on attempting to fit into a dictionary or map so I can perform a lookup for the value.

If you are left with conditions that must be checked then I would begin thinking about lambdas, delegates or custom interface. A series of `if..then` across the same type could easily be represented. Next, you would collect them and execute accordingly. IMO, this would make the `if..then` bunch much clearer. It is more code by is secondary at this point.

```
interface IInfoCheck 
{
    bool TryCheck(Info info, out string);
}

public OtherClass()
{ 
    // Setup checks
    CheckerCollection.add(new IInfoCheck{
        public String check(out result) {
           // check code 
        }
    });
}

public String method(Info info) {    
    foreach (IInfoCheck ic in CheckerCollection) 
    {
        String result = null;
        if (ic.TryCheck(out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement does not fit into an ideal chain of responsibility scenario because it is either/or kind or conditions which look 'chained' but is actually 'not'. Reason - one processes all the chain-links in the chain of responsibility pattern irrespective of what happened in the previous links, i.e. no chain-links are skipped(although you can configure which chain links to process and which not - but still the execution of a chain-link is not dependent on the outcome of a previous chain-link). However, in this if-else-if* scenario - once an if statement condition matches, the further conditions are not evaluated.

I have thought of an alternative design which achieves the above without if-else, but it is lengthier but at the same time more flexible.

Lets say we have a FunctionalInterface IfElseReplacer which takes 'info' as input and gives 'String' output.

```
public Interface IfElseReplacer(){
   public String executeCondition(Info);
}
```

Then the above conditions can be re-phrased as lambda expressions would look like - 

"(Info info) -> info.someCondition ? someString" 
"(Info info) -> info.anotherCondition ? someOtherString"
and so on...
Then we need a processConditons method to process these Lambdas- it could be a default method in ifElseReplacer -

```
default String processConditions(List<IfElseReplacer> ifElseReplacerList, Info info){
String strToReturn="lastButNotLeastString";
for(IfElseReplacer ifElseRep:ifElseReplacerList){
    strToReturn=ifElseRep.executeCondition(info);
    if(!"lastButNotLeastString".equals(strToReturn)){
         break;//if strToReturn's value changes i.e. executeCondition returns a String valueother than "lastButNotLeastString" then exit the for loop
    }
  return strToReturn;
}
```

What remains now is to (I am skipping the code for this - please let me know if you need it then will write this also) - 
From wherever the if-else conditions need to be checked there  -

1. Create an array of lambda expressions as explained above assigning them to IfElseReplacer interfaces while adding them to a list of type IfElseReplacer.
2. Pass this list to the default method processConditions() along with an instance of Info.
3. Default method would return the String value which we would be same as the result of if-else-if* block given in the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply factor out the `return`s:

```
return
    info.isSomeBooleanCondition ? "someString" :
    info.isSomeOtherCondition   ? "someOtherString" :
    info.anotherCondition       ? "anotherStringAgain" :
    lastCondition               ? "string ..." :
    "lastButNotLeastString"
;
```

Comment: It' still the same of the code above, I think: it is difficult to read, test and mantain.
The point is that if you write code without if, it's easier to write unit test. So I would like to find an elegant way to remove if-else.
I've read this article and I think it explains better why it's useful to avoid if-else: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/eliminate-branching-if-statements-to-produce-better-code

Comment: @nolanofra That article doesn't really contain any argument as to why if-else is bad. I find my snippet above easy to read and maintain.

Comment: I feel that if you could somehow use a `switch` statement this would leave the code easier to read.

Comment: @melpomene I could provide many reasons why if-else is an anti-pattern, but I think this is not the right place and the right post. The question is: Is it right to use Chain of responsability pattern on my code? Do you know any other way to remove if-else? If so, reply to the post, else don't do.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information about the problem, and the code given, it looks like this a case of type-switching. The default solution would be to use a inheritance for that:

```
class Info {
public abstract String method();
};

class BooleanCondition extends Info {
    public String method() {
         return "something";
};

class SomeOther extends Info {
    public String getString() {
         return "somethingElse";
};
```

Patterns which are interesting in this case are Decorator, Strategy and Template Method. Chain of Responsibility has another focus. Each element in the chain implement logic to process some commands. When chained, an object forwards the command if it cannot process it. This implements a loosly coupled structure to process commands where no central dispatch is needed.

If computing the string on the conditions is an operation, and from the name of the class I am guessing that it is probably an expression tree, you should look at the Visitor pattern.